# On modifying the resumptive modifier

Tags: grammaticality, resumptive-pronouns

Usually, the resumptive modifier works as follows:

> Life is all about moments, *moments that record achievements*, *moments that record time with family*.

I wonder what is the grammatical function of the italicized parts. Apposition?

The more important question is if the following grammatical?

> Life is all about moments, some moments that record achievements, but many more moments that record time with family.

Comment: The "function" of the italicized words is simply that of words in general when used to construct sentences. Perhaps what you *should* be asking about is the function of the *deleted* words whereby three statements have been collapsed into a single utterance with repeated elements discarded: ***Life is all about** moments. **Life is all about** moments that record achievements. **Life is all about** moments that record time with family.* As a stylistic alternative to *Life is all about moments that record achievements and time with family*.

Comment: Well, one "not-so-rare" exception to the traditional definition of "sentence" is when an utterance is made *within the context of a conversation* that supplies contextually relevant nouns / verbs / etc. that aren't necessarily explicitly repeated - even though strict grammar might require them for a "syntactically valid stand-alone utterance".

Comment: Many thanks for the response. Yes, I am aware of the fact that the three sentences are joined together to achieve certain effects.  What I don't know much about is how to parse this sentence grammatically. In my mind, grammar is the syntax, and sentences can be parsed into parts and components with grammatical rules without considering the contents. Because almost every sentence needs to be grammatical,  I am interested in understanding how to parse it. Again, thanks for the response.

Comment: I'm not sure it's meaningful to attempt to "parse" just the words in one "utterance" in isolation, if it's both syntactically *and* semantically bound to and modified by the surrounding context / conversation. But as to the example you ask about, I'd more likely either start a new sentence or use a dash as the separator, but it would be nit-picking to argue that any of the alternatives (including your comma) are either "grammatical" or not. They're all just stylistic orthographic choices.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is helpful. Were you talking about my first example or second example? The second example reads a bit odd, and I suspect it is not even grammatical.

Comment: Haha - I was specifically thinking about your *second* example when I wrote that. But looking at it again, I think I'd say exactly the same about the first one anyway! But I really wouldn't have a strong preference for any one orthography over another here. And it really is only "orthography" - none of it reflects anything about ***real [spoken] language***. Only real language has grammar; the written attempt to represent real language just has orthographic conventions, imho.

Comment: The second sentence seems entirely natural to me. In fact, the first sentence does not. I don't like the second comma or lack of a conjunction at the end of the first sentence. (If that second comma were replaced by *and*, I'd be fine with it.) And, yes, I would call it apposition. (Particularly, if it's "fixed.") It is clarifying a noun.

Comment: @JasonBassford, in examples I see about resumptive modifiers, it appears (for some reason I don't fully understand) people don't use *and* to connect the resumptives. Here is another example *"And so she wept for his **soul**, **a soul** entwined in distant lore, **a soul** that wandered a shadow world of near-forgotten ideas, a soul that had little hope of ever finding the light of tangible reality ever again."* I found it here: https://literatureandlibation.com/2013/03/04/craft-and-draft-resumptives-and-summatives-and-appositives-oh-my/

Comment: @TomBennett I have exactly the same comment about that sentence.

Comment: @JasonBassford, I actually think like you, too, but then every example on resumptive modifiers that I see, especially when the modifier is a noun, does not use connjunctions to link two or more resumptive nouns together. Some of the examples I find in well-regarded books on style. I wonder there is something to it. No one has explained to me why the conjunctions are not necessary.